# Windows shortcut target field, change to current directory

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have done this before, but I cannot remember how to do it.

To run the flash game I want to play you need this target in the shortcut *"DRIVE\FOLDER\flashplayer_32_sa.exe "hpbfh.swf?languageurl=hpbfh.xml"*.

The program, the .swf file and the .xml file is in the same folder as the shortcut. The shortcut and the other files will be in a zip file and when you unzip them, I want to make the shortcut work on any pc.

I am open to make a batch file to create the shortcut, but my batch knowledge is limited and I cant seem to find out how to get "hpbfh.swf?languageurl=hpbfh.xml" in the target field after creating the shortcut.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171019-00/?p=97247